# How to extract iOS CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString variables?

Tags: xcode, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, badge, fastlane

Using https://github.com/HazAT/badge I want to use xcode build version parameter and version parameter as parameters to the badge software:

```
badge --shield "Version-${version}-${buildversion}"
```

in the jenkins pipeline. Now which env parameters should I use in jenkins or how to extract the version parameters in either fastlane or jenkins pipeline?

I suppose this is about following variables:
CFBundleVersion
CFBundleShortVersionString

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [get_version_number](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/get_version_number/) action, with the [add_badge](https://github.com/HazAT/fastlane-plugin-badge) plugin. That would give you something like this:

```
version = get_version_number(target: "YOUR_APP")
add_badge(alpha:true, shield:version)
```